# Azure Durable Functions Combining fan out with function chaining

Tags: azure-durable-functions

I have a durable functions app for processing submitted items differently based on a FileName property. The Orchestrator function Resembles the below, though the below is a simplified example to illustrate my scenario.

basically, I am function chaining differently based on the extension of the FileName property in the user submitted data.

```
             InputData inputData = context.GetInput<InputData>();
        List<OutputData1> outputData1List = new List<OutputData1>();
        List<OutputData2> outputData2List = new List<OutputData2>();
        if (Path.GetExtension(inputData.FileName) == ".exa")
        {
            Func1Data func1Data = new Func1Data(inputData);
            outputData1List.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData1>("Function1", func1Data));

            Func2Data func2Data = new Func2Data(inputData);
            outputData1List.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData1>("Function2", func2Data));

            Func3Data func3Data = new Func3Data(inputData);
            outputData2List.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData2>("Function3", func3Data));
        }
        if (Path.GetExtension(inputData.FileName) == ".exb")
        {
            Func2Data func2Data = new Func2Data(inputData);
            outputData1List.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData1>("Function2", func2Data));

            Func3Data func3Data = new Func3Data(inputData);
            outputData2List.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData2>("Function3", func3Data));
        }
        if (Path.GetExtension(inputData.FileName) == ".exc")
        {
            Func3Data func3Data = new Func3Data(inputData);
            outputData2List.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData2>("Function3", func3Data));
        }
        if (Path.GetExtension(inputData.FileName) == ".exd")
        {
            Func4Data func4Data = new Func4Data(inputData);
            outputData2List.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData2>("Function4", func4Data));
        }
        return new { output1 = outputData1List, output2 = outputData2List };
```

this works ok for individual files, but I would now also like to add a second client function to my function App which accepts a batch of files containing an array of file inputs, and processes them in the same way but concurrently. Now in order to allow each file in the batch to process concurrently, I need to fan out/In. but I am unsure of how to achieve this whilst maintaining the function chaining on a per file-type basis. the below gets me a step closer, but I suspect that there is a better way to achieve this.

```
        public static async Task<Object> RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        List<InputData> batchData = context.GetInput<List<InputData>>();
        List<OutputData1> outputData1List = new List<OutputData1>();
       // List<OutputData2> outputData2List = new List<OutputData2>();

        var concurrentTasks = new List<Task<outputData2>>();

        foreach (InputData inputData in batchData)
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(inputData.FileName) == ".exa")
            {
                Func1Data func1Data = new Func1Data(inputData);
                outputData1List.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData1>("Function1", func1Data));

                Func2Data func2Data = new Func2Data(inputData);
                outputData1List.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData1>("Function2", func2Data));

                Func3Data func3Data = new Func3Data(inputData);
                concurrentTasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData2>("Function3", func3Data));
            }
            if (Path.GetExtension(inputData.FileName) == ".exb")
            {
                Func2Data func2Data = new Func2Data(inputData);
                outputData1List.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData1>("Function2", func2Data));

                Func3Data func3Data = new Func3Data(inputData);
                concurrentTasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData2>("Function3", func3Data));
            }
            if (Path.GetExtension(inputData.FileName) == ".exc")
            {
                Func3Data func3Data = new Func3Data(inputData);
                concurrentTasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData2>("Function3", func3Data));
            }
            if (Path.GetExtension(inputData.FileName) == ".exd")
            {
                Func4Data func4Data = new Func4Data(inputData);
                concurrentTasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<OutputData2>("Function4", func4Data));
            }
        }
        var outputData2List = await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
        return new { output1 = outputData1List, output2 = outputData2List };
    }
```

Instead of processing the first functions in each chain, in sequence, can I create a new Task from each function chain sequence, and batch process this? if so can anyone provide me with an example of the syntax for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: On second thought, this seems like a problem to solve with sub orchestrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub Orchestrations worked.

```
    public static async Task<Object> BatchRunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        List<InputData> batchData = context.GetInput<List<InputData>>();
        var concurrentTasks = new List<Task<Object>>();
        foreach (InputData inputData in batchData)
        {
            concurrentTasks.Add(context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<BlobFileCombinedFunctionResults>("OtherOrchestration", inputData));
        }
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
        return results;
    }
```